# C# Interactive brokers api load expiration dates for options

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

I cannot find how to read for a specific ticker, lets say "SPY", all expiration dates for options. I can read option chain given the expiration date, but I want to read the dates first so I can choose the next one and then to load the option chain for the selected date.
Any idea where is it hidden?
Thank you

Comment: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/options.html#option_chains

Comment: I am sorry, but it didnt help me. You wouldn't have a code sample, would you?
How to call it and how to retrieve the expiration dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain option chain data from Interactive Brokers TWS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607528/how-to-obtain-option-chain-data-from-interactive-brokers-tws-api)